# C# Run Function When UWP is Closed (CancelEventHandler)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, win-universal-app, speech-to-text

I am writing a **Speech To Text App** that Captures Audio from the User's Microphone, Sends Audio Stream to the Server, and Receives Text from the Server.

I am using **WebSockets** to communicate with the Server and I want the connection between App and Server to end ***only when the app closes*** (when the User presses the 'X' button on the UWP).

A quick google search directed me to use **System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler**. I used this documnetation when writing the code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing?view=net-5.0

*Side Note: I also tried using Application.Suspending Event but noticed it closed my WebSocket connection right after recording the User Audio.*

**I now get the following errors:**

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   XDG0012 The member "Closing" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   XLS0413 The property 'Closing' was not found in type 'Page'.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unknown member 'Closing' on element 'Page'

[-here is a picture of the errors-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNOnA.png)

**Here is the MainPage.xaml:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="SpeechToTextApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SpeechToTextApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Height="168" Width="410"
    Closing="OnClosing">

    <Page.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TranslucentBlackBrush" Color="Black" Opacity="1"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">


        <Button Content="Start Recording" Click="btnRec_Click" Visibility="Visible" Background="Green" x:Name="btnRec" Height="47" Width="155" Margin="31,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Stop Recording" Click="btnStop_Click" Visibility="Visible" Background="Red" x:Name="btnStop" Margin="245,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="47" Width="139"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Here is the important part of the MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Media.Capture;
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.System.Display;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace SpeechToTextApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public delegate System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler Closing();

        private static Client.Client client;

        ...

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            client = new Client.Client();
            Task task = client.ConnectToServer();

            ...
        }

        private void OnClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Task task = client.DisconnectFromServer();
            task.Wait();
        }

        ...

        void btnRec_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           ...    
        }

        async void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

'**Client**' is a namespace i wrote in a Client.cs file for App-Server communication. The Client class inside the namespace has a **ConnectToServer()** method that opens the WebSocket connection and a **DisconnectFromServer()** method that closes the WebSocket connection.

I would like to run the **DisconnectFromServer()** method when closing the app, no matter how. (just like i tried to do in **OnClosing()** function)

Comment: The [Window.Closing Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing?view=net-5.0) document mentions that this API applies to .NET Core 3.0 and 3.1. UWP only supports .NET Core 2.0. You could not use this API in UWP apps and that's the reason why you get this error message.

Answer (score 2):

To add the closing event to your application, you have to add the following to your code:

In the Package.appxmanifest add the following:

```
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
```

Add rescap to the IgnorableNamespaces:

```
IgnorableNamespaces="rescap"
```

And add this under the Capabilities tag:

```
<rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose" />
```

In your MainPage add this :

```
using Windows.UI.Core.Preview;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested += OnCloseRequest;
}

private void OnCloseRequest(object sender, SystemNavigationCloseRequestedPreviewEventArgs e)
{
    //Do whatever you want on close
    //to cancel closing use e.Handled = true;
}
```